# Format specifies type "int*" but argument has type "int"

Tags: c

Creating a code that prints out Body Mass Index

```
printf("What is your height in inches?\n");
scanf("%d", height);

printf("What is your weight in pounds?\n");
scanf("%d", weight);
```

I have height and weight as initialized as `int height`, `int weight`, but the program is not letting me run it because it says the format is type `int*` on both `scanf` lines. What am I doing wrong to get this program to run?

Comment: @The Paramagnetic Croissant  Mostly agree and more.  IMO good code checks `scanf()`, better code uses `fgets()` and checks/parses that result instead.  Robust code uses `fgets()` with all that and also handles file IO errors.  All steps may be much for OP, so promoted the first.

Comment: @chux "Robust code uses `fgets()`" - exactly.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant, I am sorry but `scanf` is good enough for scanning integers if you check the return value.

Answer (score 19):

`scanf` requires the format (your `"%d"`) and also a memory address of the variable where it should put the value that was read. `height` and `weight` are `int`, not the memory address of an `int` (this is what `int *` type 'says': a pointer to a memory address of an `int`). You should use the operator `&` to pass the memory address to `scanf`.

Your code should be:

```
printf("What is your height in inches?\n");
scanf("%d", &height);

printf("What is your weight in pounds?\n");
scanf("%d", &weight);
```

**Update**: As The Paramagnetic Croissant pointed out, reference is not the correct term.So I changed it to memory address.

Comment: What "references"? There ain't no references in C. Those are pointers.

Comment: @The Paramagnetic Croissant C does have a _referenced type_.  "A pointer type may be derived from a function type or an object type, called the referenced type" C11dr §6.2.5 20.  Perhaps this answer is using _reference_ in that context.

Comment: @chux I know about that, but the question using it is unfortunate and incorrect, since a referenced type is not the same thing as a reference, let alone a pointer.

Comment: Yeah, the term reference was wrong. I changed to memory address. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

taking into account what the other users have said, try something like this;

```
int height;                  <---- declaring your variables
int weight;
float bmi;                   <---- bmi is a float because it has decimal values

printf("What is your height in inches?\n");
scanf("%d", &height);           <----- don't forget to have '&' before variable you are storing the value in

printf("What is your weight in pounds?\n");
scanf("%d", &weight);


bmi = (weight / pow(height, 2)) * 703;    <---- the math for calculating BMI
printf("The BMI is %f\n", bmi);
```

(for this you will need to include the math.h library.)

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` reads characters from the standard input, interprets them according to the format specifiers here `"%d"` for integers and stores them in corresponding arguments.

To store them you must specify `&variable_name`, it will specify the address location where the input should be stored.

Your `scanf` statement should be:

```
//For storing value of height
scanf(" %d", &height);
//For storing value of weight
scanf(" %d", &weight);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said, it's because when you have a value that is a primitive (like an int) that is being read with scanf you have to pass the memory address to that primitive value. However, just to add something that has not been mentioned yet, the same is not true for strings.

#### Example 1. Using with a primitive value

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int primitiveInteger; // integer (i.e. no decimals allowed)
    scanf("%i", &primitiveInteger); // notice the address of operator getting the address of the primitiveInteger variable by prepending the variable name with the & (address of) operator.
    printf("Your integer is %i", primitiveInteger); simply printing it out here to the stdout stream (most likely your terminal.)
}
```

#### Example 2. Not using a primitive value

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *nonPrimitiveString; // initialize a string variable which is NOT a primitive in C
    scanf("%s", nonPrimitiveString); // notice there is no address of operator here
    printf("%s\n", nonPrimitiveString); // prints string
}
```